# Trying to learn JavaScript return greatest of 3 numbers

Tags: function, max

So I'm practicing JavaScript and I did an exercise where I defined a function that would take 2 numbers as arguments and would return the greater number. Now I'm trying to get it to return the greater of 3 numbers and it's not working right. It returns the first number if it's the highest, and will return the 2nd number if it's great than the first. but nothing is happening with the 3rd number. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code and my solution isn't working? My code below. thank you.

```
function maxOfThree(num1, num2, num3) {
   if (num1 > num2 && num3) {
       return num1;
   } else if (num2 > num1 && num3) {
       return num2;
   } else {
       return num3;
   }
}

alert(maxOfThree(4,12,23));
```

Comment: Or just use `Math.max` like so `Math.max(4,12,23)`.  Good to know what is available in the language when you are learning.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that instead of putting

Answer (score 1):

Simple error. The `&&` operand means "and" in the logical sense (3 > 2 *and* 3 > 1), not in a semantic sense (3 > 2 *and* 1). Javascript still accepts your code because `num3`  could be a boolean value (3 > 1 and [true or false]; variables are not restricted to a type in JS).

Use `num1 > num3 && num1 > num3` instead of `num1 > num2 && num3`.

Comment: Yves, thanks! the exercise specifically said to use and if/else statement. I ended up finding the solution myself and I was in the middle of commenting that I fixed it when my computer shut down and started coniguring windows updates. >_< but thanks for the response! And thanks to everyone else who had other solutions, while they weren't exactly what I was looking for it's great to know that are other ways to produce the same result.!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused about order of operations. Stepping through your code we get the following:

```
function maxOfThree(num1, num2, num3) {

   // return num1 if num1 is larger than num2 and if num3 is not 0 (or a falsy value)
   if (num1 > num2 && num3) {
       return num1;
   // otherwise return num2 if num2 is larger than num1 and if num3 is not 0
   } else if (num2 > num1 && num3) {
       return num2;
   // otherwise return num3
   } else {
       return num3;
   }
}
```

You can see that `num3` never actually gets compared to `num1` or `num2`.